# Cross browser problem with <div> tab

Tags: css, browser

I have created  `<div>` element, i am doing show/hide that `<div>` using java script..

but the problem is that the position of that  varies on all different browsers

javascript is as follows

```
 <  script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var abc=false;
function showHide()
{
var a=document.getElementById("MainDiv");
var b=document.getElementById("myTestDiv");

if(abc==false)
{
abc=true;
b.style.top = a.offsetTop;
b.style.left = a.offsetParent;
b.style.display = "inline";
}
else{
abc=false;
b.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

html is as follows

```
 <div id="myTestDiv" style="border: 2px solid rgb(100, 149, 237); color:#23238e; background-color:#FFFFFF; position:absolute; width:14%; height:17%; display:none" >
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code so people can see what's happening?

Comment: In order to hide a given DOM element you don't need it's position. You only need to have a reference to it. For example if this div has an id you could use the document.getElementById function to find it. As far as the position of the div is concerned that's probably CSS problem that you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Why `b.style.left = a.offsetParent;` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/OffsetParent

I think you want `b.style.left = a.offsetLeft;`. Anyway, why you use JavaScript for this? Can't you set `position: relative;` of `MainDiv` and `top: 0; left: 0;` of `myTestDiv`?

Comment: I'm embarrassed that I didn't notice `b.style.left = a.offsetParent`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with installing [BluePrint CSS Framework](http://blueprintcss.org) and retry your action again again!

Or deliver us some more information about your issue...

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided enough information here, but I'll take a few guesses anyway..

```
b.style.display = "inline";
```

Instead of `inline`, you probably want to be setting it to `block`, what with the fact that `div`s are block-level elements.

Something else to try, append `px`:

```
b.style.top = a.offsetTop + "px";
b.style.left = a.offsetParent + "px";
```

Also, make sure you have a proper doctype as the *very first line*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without that, Internet Explorer in particular will be hopelessly broken.

Comment: Thanks thirtydot, its working, but gives slight difference in google chrome

Comment: @abc: To help you, I need to see what you have. Paste your entire HTML into [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), and include any relevant CSS inside a `<style> YOUR CSS HERE </style>`.